# Откуда появляется отступ?

Tags: веб-программирование, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        html, body, #wrapper, #all {height: 100%; margin: 0;}
        #wrapper {width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;}
        #main {min-height: 100%; margin-bottom: -100px; background: yellow;}
        footer {height: 100px; background: blue;}
        #all {padding-bottom: 100px;}
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="all">
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
            <p>text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот код. Объясните, отступы какого элемента создают пространство вверху страницы?
Знаю, что если * все обнулить, то будет все ОК. Но хотелось бы понять причину.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы

Comment: @Дмитрий Сафонов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это стандартные настройки Вашего браузера (user agent stylesheet так называемые). Для их обнуления лучше использовать reset.css или normalize.css. Ответ на Ваш вопрос - тег p. То, что Вы задали `margin: 0` для `#all`, роли не играет, так как [margin не наследуется](http://htmlbook.ru/css/margin).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае на отступы влияет элемент <p>. Добавьте его в перечисляемый список и получите нужный эффект:

```
html, body, #wrapper, #all, p, footer {margin: 0;}
```

По умолчанию элемент <p> имеет свойства margin-top и margin-bottom,  равные 16px. Но, чтоб не мучиться, используют универсальный селектор звёздочки (*), чтоб  выбрать все элементы на странице.